# Why does upvoting a question enable the "Other action" option in review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

If you upvote on a question while reviewing, the "Other action" option is enabled and allows you to select it.

That doesn't make sense to me since upvoting a question/answer implies it is well-written enough to satisfy passing review.

If a question/answer is downvoted, then obviously the "Other action" option should be enabled so that you may select it if desired.

Downvoting and "Other action" aren't mutually inclusive, but I think upvoting and "Looks OK" should be.

Thus, I don't think upvoting during a review should enable the "Other action" option.

Comment: "I think upvoting and "Looks OK" should be [mutually exclusive]" did you mean "Other action"? Seems kind of backwards as written.

Comment: Requiring someone who only cast an upvote to pick "Looks OK" would also be useful for moderators attempting to check the accuracy of reviews, as "Reviewed" is currently extremely unhelpful.  Narrowing down the possibilities a bit (especially with moderators' ability to see most of the other effects) would allow us to better determine if the review was correct.

Comment: Oh...!?,  I thought "Reviewed" (= completely vague for "Other Action") (only) meant ['Edit' | 'Comment' | 'VTC']...

Comment: This is historical. In the past, the buttons used to be titled "No Action Needed" and "I'm Done". The former button was when you chose to take no action, not even casting an up vote, and would disable itself once you've taken some action, with the latter button becoming enabled instead. That the modern former button still remains enabled is a new change (uncertain if intentional or a bug), but the modern latter button enabling itself is a carry-over from the old version of the review queue.